# Case distinction without constructors in Isabelle function definition

Tags: isabelle

How can I write function subst below in Isabelle?

```
datatype AForm = int 

datatype Form = AForm 

fun substA :: "AForm  ⇒ AForm"
  where
"substA F  = undefined"

fun subst :: "Form ⇒ Form"
  where
"subst (φ::AForm) = substA φ"
```

This will fail with:

```
Type unification failed: Clash of types "AForm" and "Form"

Type error in application: incompatible operand type

Operator:  subst :: Form ⇒ char list ⇒ texp ⇒ Form
Operand:   φ :: AForm
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear what you tried to achieve here.

**My guess**

You are getting the meaning of datatype wrong.

```
datatype AForm = int
```

means that you are creating a datatype with a single value called `int`. It has absolutely nothing to do with the type `int`.

I added some dummy constructor names that have a type has parameter (`int` and `AForm`:

```
datatype AForm = A int 

datatype Form = F AForm 

fun substA :: "AForm  ⇒ AForm"
  where
"substA (A f)  = undefined"

fun subst :: "Form ⇒ Form"
  where
"subst (F φ) = F (substA φ)"
```

**Alternative guess**

If you intended to introduce another name for int, use `type_synonym` for that purpose.

Comment: Mathias, what I showed above is a simplification of the actual code. If you see the first version of the question you will see that in fact I have a more complex grammar for Form and AForm. I'm explicitly interested to see if it can be done in Isabelle without the dummy constructors that you introduced to follow closely the syntax of the paper I'm reading. Thanks for your time.

Comment: In theory, you probably can get that behavior with coercions. Whether the very weird typing errors you will get out of it are really worth it, is unclear to me